# Show citation in footnote and in references when using \cite

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

Iam having a small problem getting biblatex to do what i want. The following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=footnote-dw,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % references

% Style TOC and page links
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,plainpages=false,pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true,pdfpagelabels,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}

\bibliography{refs}

\begin{document}

Lorem \cite{Foo} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac lorem nec sapien aliquam sagittis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec eu odio purus. Fusce accumsan placerat lectus, at pellentesque neque venenatis nec. Praesent egestas neque sit amet dignissim aliquam. Nam viverra mollis orci sed bibendum. Ut vitae eros dapibus, convallis leo a, varius enim. Nulla volutpat lectus sit amet imperdiet facilisis.

Etiam in rhoncus libero. Donec nulla sem, sollicitudin vel quam id, luctus imperdiet    lectus. Proin rhoncus nisi a lorem dignissim ultricies. Aenean placerat egestas diam, sed vestibulum mi dignissim quis. Aliquam pretium laoreet tempor. Ut eget rhoncus sapien. Nulla blandit nisl eget orci pharetra, eu condimentum diam accumsan. Sed pharetra pellentesque mi, a pulvinar risus semper a. Sed odio neque, molestie eu risus et, feugiat tincidunt turpis. Cras mattis neque non tellus auctor, id faucibus dolor egestas. Etiam vitae luctus orci. Vestibulum faucibus dolor leo, id dignissim odio convallis sit amet. Donec id rhoncus eros,       non commodo eros. Ut tincidunt eu justo in rutrum.\cite{Bar}

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}
```

The following image shows the current output. What i look for is to have the numbering in square bracking from all the citations throughout the report.

Hope someone can help out :D

[image: current output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `footnote-dw` is not a numeric style, it is quite a verbose footnote citation style. You just redefined the footnotes to always be in square brackets, which is not a good idea (try to add a normal footnote!). If you want proper numeric citations, better use `style=numeric`, and modify it to your needs (ask a new question for that).